# How to get Laravel validation errors in react component which is in Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to React. I'm using react form component **partially** in the Laravel blade. Then how can I send validation error messages from controllers to that react component which is resides in the Laravel blade file.

In my Controller,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
      'name' => 'required',
      'publish_at' => 'required|datetime'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $book = Book::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'publish_at' => $request->publish_at
    ]);

    return response()->json($book);
}
```

In my laravel blade,

```
 <form method="POST" action="patients">
     @csrf
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="name">Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder=". . .">
         @error('name')
         <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
         @enderror
     </div>

     <div id="publish_at"></div> <!-- this is react component -->

     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Kindly provide some code so that we can try to understand the situation better.

Answer (score 1):

> According to Laravel docs, they send a response with 422 code on
>   failed validation:
>
> If the incoming request was an AJAX request, no redirect will be
>   generated. Instead, an HTTP response with a 422 status code will be
>   returned to the browser containing a JSON representation of the
>   validation errors

```
*So, you just need to handle response and, if validation failed, add a
validation message to the state, something like in the following code
snippet*


  request = $.ajax({ 
              url: "/user", 
              type: "post", 
              data: 'email=' + email + '&_token={{ csrf_token() }}',
              data: {'email': email, '_token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')},
              beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);},
              error: function(jqXhr, json, errorThrown) {
                if(jqXhr.status === 422) {
                    //status means that this is a validation error, now we need to get messages from JSON
                    var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON;
                    var theMessageFromRequest = errors['email'].join('. ');
                    this.setState({
                        validationErrorMessage: theMessageFromRequest,
                        submitted: false
                    });
                }
              }.bind(this)
        });
```

After that, in the 'render' method, just check if `this.state.validationErrorMessage` is set and render the message somewhere:

```
render: function() {
    var text = this.state.submitted ? 'Thank you!  Expect a follow up at '+email+' soon!' : 'Enter your email to request early access:';
    var style = this.state.submitted ? {"backgroundColor": "rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.4)"} : {};
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.submitted ? null :
            <div className="overall-input">
              <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}>
                  <input type="email" className="input_field" onChange={this._updateInputValue} ref="email" value={this.state.email} />
                  <div className="validation-message">{this.state.validationErrorMessage}</div>
                  <div className="button-row">
                      <a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Request Invite</a>
                  </div> 
              </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>                            
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
```